# 'SDL_INIT' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, sdl-2

this:

```
#include <iostream>
#define SDL_MAIN_HANDLED
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
  if (SDL_INIT( SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING ) < 0 )
  {
      std::cout << " error starting SDL " <<SDL_GetError( ) << std::endl;
  }
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

returns:

```
||=== Build: Debug in test (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
C:\Development\Projects\test\main.cpp||In function 'int main(int, char**)':|
C:\Development\Projects\test\main.cpp|7|error: 'SDL_INIT' was not declared in this scope|
||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

saw this: [undefined reference to SDL_Init](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30146283/undefined-reference-to-sdl-init), and changed my SDL2 version to 32 bit, the error still comes up. Very new to this so apologies if this is a stupid question.

Comment: `SDL_INIT` != `STD_Init`

Answer (score 5):

The right syntax is SDL_Init() not SDL_INIT().

https://www.libsdl.org/release/SDL-1.2.15/docs/html/sdlinit.html